# Динамическое изменение SolidColorBrush в App.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf

Пытаюсь добавить настройку цветов в программе (по нажатию кнопки) для этого использую Solidcolorbrush(прописаны в App.xaml), но я не знаю как обратиться к ним через MaimWindow.xaml.cs.Буду рад любой помощи, заранее “Спасибо”.

```
<ResourceDictionary>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ForegroundBrush" Color="Red"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackgroundBrush_1"  Color="Purple"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackgroundBrush_2"  Color="White"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

а вот так пытался их изменить

```
SolidColorBrush buttonBrush =(SolidColorBrush)this.TryFindResource("BackgroundBrush_1");
buttonBrush.Color = Colors.LimeGreen;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать следующий код для изменения значения конкретного элемента в словаре:

```
Resources["BackgroundBrush_1"] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LimeGreen);
```

Это изменение повлияет только на те элементы, которые используют `DynamicResource`.

```
 <TextBlock Text="Test Static Resource" FontSize="18" Grid.Row="0" 
   Foreground="{StaticResource ForegroundBrush}"
   Background="{StaticResource BackgroundBrush_1}"/>
 <TextBlock Text="Test Dynamic Resource" FontSize="18" Grid.Row="1" 
   Foreground="{DynamicResource ForegroundBrush}"
   Background="{DynamicResource BackgroundBrush_1}"/>
```

В этом примере, первый блок использует `StaticResource`, который получает значение при инициализации, и использует его на протяжении всей своей жизни. Второй блок использует `DynamicResource`, который реагирует на изменения в словаре.